# Find word containing punctuation, but not in the end or word

Tags: regex, find, period

I'm breaking my head about following problem. I need to match dot in the word under certain condition.

Example:

```
D.A.R.Y.L. or se.ven or go/the    will be untreated.
Dr. Odissey. or look, or look:    will be treated.
```

I was using before:

```
([A-Z]+[.\\-/]+)+([A-Z]+[.\\-/]?)*
```

It was partially working, but it wouldn't distinguish for `Dr. Odissey.` and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'untreated' and 'treated'. Could you clarify?

Comment: How would you handle the following: `the qui.ck brown fox` or `jumped over the d.og?` or `Hey, Lady! You call him Dr.!`

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern in Java style:

```
(?<!\\S)[A-Za-z]+\\p{Punct}(?!\\S)
```

you can replace `\\p{Punct}` with the punctuation characters of your choice `[.,:;]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for words optionally ending with punctuation you can use

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\p{P}?(?=\s|$)
```

`\b` is a non word boundary

`\p{P}` matches any punctuation character

`(?=\s|$)` would check for a space or end of string

Answer (score 0):

It seems (?) that you want to match/replace a dot if (and only if) it's followed by whitespace or the end of the string. Is that correct?

In that case, assuming you want to change dots into exlamation marks,

```
newString = oldString.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\s)(\\w+)\\.(?=\\s|$)", "$1!");
```

will change

```
D.A.R.Y.L. or se.ven or go/the Dr. Odissey. or look, or look:
```

into

```
D.A.R.Y.L. or se.ven or go/the Dr! Odissey! or look, or look:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to find the dots inside a word then you can use this

```
\b[.]\b
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/SUZz_tWtL4iPp4cb)

Or if you're only looking for dots at the end of words, then try this

```
\b[.](?:\s|$)|(?:^|\s)[.]\b
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/DtIb2A2M9-Qlx_9-)

Of course this will match the `.` after `D.A.R.Y.L.`